# Android: String equals and contains not matching

Tags: java, android, string

I'm testing out the JSON functionality for an Android application and have the following JSON object.

```
{"result":"fail"}
```

I then use the following code to get my value:

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(ReturnValue); //Return value is what's shown above
String r = jObject.getString("result");
```

Then using the following I don't get a match

```
if(r.trim() == "fail")
```

I wrote it out to the screen just to make sure with this:

```
et.setText("-" + r + "-");
```

That results in -fail-

I don't understand why this doesn't match.  If I used r.Contains it returns true, but I can't use that for my checks.

Comment: Use the `equals` method for comparison, not `==`.

Comment: Thanks, if you put that as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: No worries mate, you can accept one of the ones below. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use equals `.equals` instead of `==`. This is because of in Java, if you use `==` you compare the Object pointers to each other. In the source code of `String` they have overriden the `equals` method so they instead compare the letters.

You can't override operators in Java.

Also this is general, always use `equals` for any object comparison if you don't want to check the references you are comparing are **actually** pointing on the same object in the heap.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Coming from C# they're so close in syntax I sometimes just assume something will work.

Comment: actually, C# also has a similar gotcha with strings, equals and ==. Only it's hidden deeper.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
if(r.trim().equals("fail"))
```

to compare Strings.

Answer (score -2):

as others pointed out, in Java == means "exactly the same object", not "an identical object". You can have two, say, SimpleDateFormat objects that are identical, yet if they occupy different places on the heap, they are not the same object. fyi, C# behaves in quite similar way, but manages to hide it from programmers [most of the time](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx).

btw, Since you are already writing Java code, it might be a good idea to, you know, study the language a bit. Saves an awful lot of problems later on. A lot of other surprises await for people who try to write C# in Java (like non-static inner classes).

Comment: hmmm... strange? can I have some kind of feedback on the downvotes? non-static inner classes *are* a big gotcha for C++/C# people who don't bother to read up on Java (and cause memory leaks in real apps) AND my explanation of equals versus == is quite accurate... the link provides more information. So - just out of curiosity - why?